# counting words inside a webpage

Tags: python-3.x, urllib2, urllib, urllib3

I need to count words that are inside a webpage using python3. Which module should I use? urllib?

Here is my Code:

```
def web():
    f =("urllib.request.urlopen("https://americancivilwar.com/north/lincoln.html")
    lu = f.read()
    print(lu)
```

Comment: The above code is just to read the webpage not to count but i just want to get access to the distinct words first.

Comment: You could use bs4 and get all the text and then find the `len` of it

Comment: For starters you should remove the `("` from `f =("urllib` so that it says `f = urllib`.

Comment: my code gave me even the html codes so I need to remove them. How may i do that?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

With below self explained code you can get a good starting point for counting words within a web page:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from collections import Counter
from string import punctuation

# We get the url
r = requests.get("https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Khalil_Gibran")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

# We get the words within paragrphs
text_p = (''.join(s.findAll(text=True))for s in soup.findAll('p'))
c_p = Counter((x.rstrip(punctuation).lower() for y in text_p for x in y.split()))

# We get the words within divs
text_div = (''.join(s.findAll(text=True))for s in soup.findAll('div'))
c_div = Counter((x.rstrip(punctuation).lower() for y in text_div for x in y.split()))

# We sum the two countesr and get a list with words count from most to less common
total = c_div + c_p
list_most_common_words = total.most_common()
```

If you want for example the first 10 most common words you just do:

```
total.most_common(10)
```

Which in this case outputs:

```
In [100]: total.most_common(10)
Out[100]: 
[('the', 2097),
 ('and', 1651),
 ('of', 998),
 ('in', 625),
 ('i', 592),
 ('a', 529),
 ('to', 529),
 ('that', 426),
 ('is', 369),
 ('my', 365)]
```

Comment: I don't know who gave me downvote for this question. down vote for no reason.

Comment: Not me. By the way if you found my answer useful please consider to upvote/accept it.

Comment: My vote is not counted because of inadequate reputation. However, you have my up vote. I was just wandering if I can check python codes for plagiarism but I am not getting any response from anyone.

Comment: You can accept answers with the tick under the up and down vote

Comment: Okay I just did that and thank you. Do you know of any online websites to check code for plagiarism for free? If i may ask?

Comment: No. Sorry. I don't know. You may ask a new question for that. Good luck.

Comment: I found the above method might output not exact numbers as a paragraph can be within a div and viceversa. Nos sure how it works, but I found an interesting tool online for checking word counts within a website: https://wordcounter.net/website-word-count

Comment: Using this with the example URL given (https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Kahlil_Gibran) shows it vastly overstates the words. E.g. CTRL+F and searching "the" on the actual page only returns 687 results at the time of writing, while this says "the" appears 2139 times.

Comment: @ZhouW you are right. The problem resides that many web pages have 'div' and 'p' one within the other or viceversa, as I mentioned in mi previous comment.

Comment: Interesting, another tool I found that does the exact same thing pretty accurate webpage word counter https://randomtools.io/webpage-word-counter/