# Counting words in a webpage is inaccurate

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Noob, trying to build a word counter, to count the words displayed on a website. I found some code ([counting words inside a webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46271528/counting-words-inside-a-webpage)), modified it, tried it on Google, and found that it was way off. Other code I tried displayed all of the various HTML tags, which was likewise not helpful. If visible page content reads: "Hello there world," I'm looking for a count of 3. For now, I'm not concerned with words that are in image files (pictures). My modified code is as follows:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from collections import Counter
from string import punctuation

# Page you want to count words from
page = "https://google.com"

# Get the page
r = requests.get(page)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

# We get the words within paragrphs
text_p = (''.join(s.findAll(text=True))for s in soup.findAll('p'))
# creates a dictionary of words and frequency from paragraphs
content_paras = Counter((x.rstrip(punctuation).lower() for y in text_p for x in y.split()))
sum_of_paras = sum(content_paras.values())

# We get the words within divs
text_div = (''.join(s.findAll(text=True))for s in soup.findAll('div'))
content_div = Counter((x.rstrip(punctuation).lower() for y in text_div for x in y.split()))
sum_of_divs = sum(content_div.values())

words_on_page = sum_of_paras + sum_of_divs
print(words_on_page)
```

As always, simple answers I can follow are appreciated over complex/elegant ones I cannot, b/c Noob.

Comment: Can you provide some examples with results? I ran your code and returned 47 words which is correct with the google homepage. It's counting words in all collapsible content and links as well.

Comment: Thanks for looking. I'm trying to find code that only counts words that are visible when the page is displayed. So on the https://www.webpagetest.org/ page for instance, there are a few hundred words visible, and the above code returns 13k in change, which is obviously way off.

Comment: I think that would depend on the webpage / script that is generating the hidden elements. We see on the google home page, there're different classes / attributes that indicate an element is hidden. But this will vary from site to site so I don't think it'd be possible to make a general script to count only visible words.

Comment: Found this tool, very accurate and works well - https://randomtools.io/webpage-word-counter/